# Popup form validation in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I have a **popup model** with following fields

- name
- email
- comment box
- submit button with input type=”button”

I displayed this **form** in a popup model.

Now I need to validate these fields. Is there any solution to validate these input fields in magento 2?

```
    <form>
    <h3>Feedback form</h3>
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <label>Suggestion:</label>
    <select name="selectname" id="suggestion">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="on product">On product</option>
        <option value="on delivery">On delivery</option>
        <option value="on usability">On usability</option>
        <option value="criticism">Criticism</option>
        <option value="others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <label>Comments:</label><textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="comments"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="feedbackBtn">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not submitting your form using a submit button with type "submit" then you should use jquery on click of your button and then validate your form according to your requirements.

Follow [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/) for form validation using jquery.

You can validate email too using jquery, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507030/email-validation-using-jquery) for various ways to achieve this.

Also you can use the following event if you use type='sibmit'

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    // Your validations
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // if(not valid){
        return false;
    // }
})
```

Comment: Yes I am using onclick event . but in this tutorial they have used type submit. How I should validate by using button as input type?

Comment: You can use it with type button as well, also check  [this link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2016/01/how-to-validate-forms-using-jquery) Also check my answer, I have edited for type='submit'

Answer (score 0):

You should re-create your form with the help of this customer registration file. It has validation classes and attributes which you can use the exact same way.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

NOTE: if you want to add server side validation then you can reference this

```
vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has build in validation methods. You can check default modeles templates like vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml

and use data-validate attribute like this

```
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/) tutorial.

It works perfectly for me